# Proper way to pause a setinterval on a beforeSend ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have this code.

```
 var centerTimer = 0;
    function startCenterRefresh( refreshTime,position,params ) {
        centerTimer = setInterval(function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: host+"/forms/refresh-center.php",
                beforeSend:function(){ stopCenterRefresh(); },
                success: function(){console.log(1);},
                complete:function(){startCenterRefresh(refreshTime,position,params);}
            });
        },refreshTime);
    }

    function stopCenterRefresh() {
        clearInterval( centerTimer );
    }
```

Is this the proper way to pause a setInterval on a beforeSend on an ajax request then resume the setInterval after the ajax request is complete?
I'm not sure if I met my expectation on this execution.

Your idea would be greatly appreciated and rewarded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clearInterval` doesn't pause the periodic call to a function : it removes it. So you're totally stopping it at the first call. It's thus ineffective.

What you probably should do is simply requeue (using `setTimeout`) the ajax call in the success callback.

For example :

```
var call = function() {
    $.ajax({ ... }).done(function(...){
       ...
       setTimeout(call, refreshTime);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Using settimeout is the other way around though to meet my requirement on my application. Thanks again :)